# Password_verify not working with mysql

Tags: password-recovery

I am using `password_hash` function to insert hash into database as part of user registration. This works well and a password hash is created in the database. However, I am unable to verify the password using `password_verify`, with the check always returning false. For example:

```
    $hash = password_hash("rattle",PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

    returns `$hash = $2y$10$fonFqdioDtfJ/Gp7t4orWOdalMHkKQSA8PrFvbgI7LC0LCvYshZ.i`
```

This is successfully inserted into the database. However, `password_verify('rattle',$hash)` always returns `false`. I have tried echoing the hash before it is inserted into the database and using that as the hash, but still no joy. The database hash field is setup as 60 char.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tested, works on both saved string and dynamic. Always 60 chars.

```
$hash = password_hash("rattle",PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$hashCheckSaved = password_verify("rattle", '$2y$10$KDIzEQjsmlHCP0mjixbBoe9yJE8tY4aNPOZegiwez1zUPkt5217M2');
$hashCheckDynamic = password_verify("rattle", $hash);
echo $hash."<br> saved(". $hashCheckSaved . ") dynamic(". $hashCheckDynamic.")";
echo "<br>";
echo strlen($hash) . " chars in this string";
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't $hashCheckSaved = password_verify("rattle",'$2y$10$fonFqdioDtfJ/Gp7t4orWOdalMHkKQSA8PrFvbgI7LC0LCvYshZ.i'), using the saved hashed in the database? This always returns false.

Comment: hashcheckSaved is emulating a hash from the db. make sure you are wrapping single quotes around it.